# Django Rest Framework Limiting get_queryset result to not include all fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

view.py

```
class charity_totals(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class= CharityTotalSerializer
    queryset=Transaction.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        user_id = self.request.GET.get('userID')
        if user_id is None:
            return queryset
        queryset = queryset.filter(userID=user_id)
        return queryset.values('charityID').annotate(total_donation=Sum('transactionAmount'))
```

serializer.py

```
class CharityTotalSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    charity_name= serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='charityID.charityName')
    total_donation= serializer.DecimalField(max_digits=64,decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['charity_name','total_donation']
```

model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transactionAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    charityID = models.ForeignKey(Charity,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='charity_set')
    processed = models.BooleanField(auto_created=True, default=False)
    transactionDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Off of a request such as this http://localhost:8000/requests/charitytotal/?userID=1 my json response is limited to just the [{"total_donation":"3.00"},{"total_donation":"17.00"}] and is not including the charity names that are specified in the serializer. From what I understand the .values should return a dict of both the charityID and the total_donation that was specified which should be able to interact with my serializer. Any Insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are returning Values queryset from `get_queryset` method when you are getting the value of `userID` in request.GET. Also I assume it is important for you return that way so that you can group by and sum values of total donation. So, I think you can approach something like this:

First, change get_queryset method to return the name of the charity annotated:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum
...

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    user_id = self.request.GET.get('userID')
    if user_id is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(userID=user_id)
    return queryset.values('charityID').annotate(total_donation=Sum('transactionAmount')).annotate(charity_name=F('charityID__charityName'))
```

Then update the serializer like this:

```
class CharityTotalSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    charity_name= serializer.ReadOnlyField()  # no need to define source
    total_donation= serializer.DecimalField(max_digits=64,decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['charity_name','total_donation']
```

Also, better to have `charityName` unique(using `unique=True` in models), so that it does not produce confusing results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it into Serializer and it will work fine.

```
charity_name = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

def get_charity_name(self, instance):
    return instance.charityID.name
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers